# Java array - eliminate intermediary consecutive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to write an algorithm that pretty much does this with a sorted array full of integers:

1) {8,9,10,14,15,16,19,20,21} -> {8,10,14,16,19,21}

2) {8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,18,19,20,21} -> {8,12,14,16,18,21}

I've come up with this algorithm:

```
int l=x.length;    
        for(int k=0;k<l-1;k++)
        {
            if (x[k]+1==x[k+1] && x[k]+2==x[k+2])
            {
                for(int z=k+1;z<l;z++)
                {
                    if(z+1==l)
                        x[z]=0;
                    else
                    x[z]=x[z+1];
                }                
                l--;
            }
        }
```

This algorithm works well with the above mentioned first example but if I instead put more than 3 consecutive numbers it screws up the result, for example:

{8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,18,19,20,21} -> {8,10,12,14,16,18,20,21} instead of {8,12,14,16,18,21}

What am I doing wrong? And how can I change my algorithm to successfully eliminate all intermediary consecutive numbers

Comment: If you have a sequence of 2 consecutive numbers, you keep both? (2,3,4,5,10,11) => (2,5,10,11) ?

Comment: Is it a requirement to do the compacting in place (i.e. in the same array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tunaki is right.

I'd do something along the lines of this:

```
public static int[] filterImmediary(int[] x) {

    /*
     * Construct a boolean array that will be used to indicate whether the
     * corresponding element in the int array is an immediary consecutive
     * number.
     */
    int l = x.length;
    boolean[] rem = new boolean[l];
    int numKeeps = 0;

    /*
     * Fill boolean array
     */
    for (int k = 0; k < l - 1; k++) {
        int f = 1;
        while (k + f < l && x[k] + f == x[k + f]) {
            if (k + f + 1 < l && x[k] + f + 1 == x[k + f + 1]) {
                rem[k + f] = true;
            }
            f++;
        }
        if (!rem[k]) {
            numKeeps++;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Construct a new array with no immediary consecutive numbers to return
     * instead of mutating the original array.
     */
    int[] newX = new int[numKeeps+1];
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
        if (!rem[k]) {
            newX[i] = x[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return newX;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the while loop and if block could be reworked and optimized

Comment: Yes, this helped me a lot, the idea of creating a boolean array was exactly what i needed. Also I appreciate the time and effort it took to write the code.

Answer (score 3):

When you find in your array 3 consecutive numbers (let's say `x[k]`, `x[k+1]` and `x[k+2]`, you shift every numbers to the left, dropping the middle number. So, among others, `x[k+1]` becomes what was `x[k+2]`. What you are left with are not consecutive numbers anymore (because `x[k] + 2 == x[k+2]`), so no matter what `x[k+3]` was, you going to keep `x[k+2]` around (this is what happened in your second example, where 10 was left).

The culprit is this line : `if (x[k]+1==x[k+1] && x[k]+2==x[k+2])`. This line does not actually say what you want it to say. It will only match for 3 consecutive numbers, but you want to match more. In fact, you want to match as many consecutive numbers as possible. One way to do that would be to use a `while` loop: while numbers are consecutive, keep searching until it ends (or you hit the end of the array). Once it ends, you can then shift the remaining part of the array, just like you did, only not by one but by as many numbers you found.

Answer (score 0):

@Tunaki gives the reason, here is one commented solution:

```
public static void compactIt(int[] x) {
    int l = x.length;    
    int k = 0;
    while (k < l-1) {
        // find end of sequence of consecutive numbers
        int endSeq = k;
        while (endSeq < l-1 && x[endSeq]+1 == x[endSeq+1]) {
            endSeq++;
        }
        // how many numbers we have to compact?
        int numToSkip = endSeq - k - 1;
        if (numToSkip == -1) {
            // following number is not consecutive, just move to it
            k++;
        }
        else if (numToSkip == 0) {
            // there is only one consecutive number, keep both, move of 2
            k += 2;
        }
        else { 
            // there is at least 3 numbers in the sequence, 
            // copy numbers from the last in sequence to the end
            for (int z = k+1; (z+numToSkip) < l; z++) {
                x[z] = x[z+numToSkip];
            }
            // set ending slots to 0
            for (int z = l-numToSkip; z < l; z++) {
                x[z] = 0;
            }
            l = l-numToSkip;
            k += 2;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 20, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40};
    compactIt(x);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
}
```

Prints: `[1, 4, 10, 11, 20, 30, 34, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Yes, it's good, I'll upvote it when I can(don't have enough reputation yet). 
Though, later I will use the resulted array and I can't have any zero's left in it. It can be done by creating a new array, of exactly the size of numbers not equal to 0 in this one, and storing these numbers into it, but it only complicates the program.